# Comparing Multiple Values from one table to Multiple Values in another

Tags: plsql, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper, stored-functions, data-dictionary

I have a PL/SQL stored function script I am writing and I have run into a problem.

I need to find ALL Applicants who possess ALL the skills needed for a task and display them.

I have a method where I have individually read in Applicant's skills into a `VARCHAR2` string and all the Skills required into another. If I could separate these strings into individual words I could compare the two with `LIKE '% <data> %'`.

How would I go about this (or what is an alternative method)?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUBARR(num IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR IS
  string_position VARCHAR2(128);
  string_applicant VARCHAR2(128);
  string_results VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN  
  string_position := '';
  string_applicant := '';


  FOR SKILLS_row IN (SELECT sname FROM SNEEDED WHERE pnumber = num)
  LOOP
    string_position := string_position || SKILLS_row.sname || ' ';
  END LOOP;

  FOR EVERYBODY_row IN (SELECT UNIQUE anumber FROM SPOSSESSED ORDER BY anumber)
  LOOP
    FOR APPLICANTS_row IN (SELECT sname FROM SPOSSESSED WHERE SPOSSESSED.anumber = EVERYBODY_row.anumber)
    LOOP 
        string_applicant := string_applicant || APPLICANTS_row.sname || ' ';
    END LOOP;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EVERYBODY_row.anumber || ' ' || string_applicant);


    --IF blaah != LIKE BLAh
    IF 


    string_applicant := '';
  END LOOP;


  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(string_position);
  --RETURN (string_position);
  RETURN('help');
END FUBARR;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

why not simply select all spossesed - records, where the number of associated skills of the desired `num` is equal to the plain number of sneeded - skills of that `num`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SPOSSESSED sp
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SNEEDED s 
         WHERE s.pnumber = num) =
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SNEEDED s 
          JOIN SPOSSESSED p ON p.sname = s.sname 
         WHERE s.pnumber = num and p.anumber = sp.anumber)
```

or using the ANY construct:

```
SELECT sp.anumber, COUNT(*) 
  FROM SPOSSESSED sp
 WHERE sp.sname = ANY (SELECT s.sname FROM SNEEDED s WHERE s.pnumber = num)
 GROUP BY sp.anumber
```